# a UnitTest that passed in Matlab 2016B fails in Mablab 2017A-pre-release: TestParameter not defined

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I have a unit test class heyrarchy:

```
classdef TFbe <  ITAlgo % concrete class
classdef  ( Abstract ) ITAlgo < matlab.unittest.TestCase % abstract class
```

in ITAlgo, i implemented a function that supplies a common service:

```
function do_run_time( testCase, args, num_of_iterations )
```

and an abstract test function:

```
run_time ( testCase ) ;
```

the abstract function is implemented in CFbe, and this implementation calls do_run_time.
This works well, and the test passes, in Matlab 2016B (Windows 7, 64 bit version).
now, i downloaded the new Matlab 2017A-pre-release (Windows 7, 64 bit version), and it fails.

i get the folowing error (orange font):

> Warning: Concrete class TFbe does not define a TestParameter property
>   named args for the do_run_time method. Either implement the property
>   or define the class as Abstract. This warning will become an error in
>   a future release. 
>   Warning: Concrete class TFbe does not define a
>   TestParameter property named num_of_iterations for the do_run_time
>   method. Either implement the property or define the class as Abstract.
>   This warning will become an error in a future release.

then I get the error message (red font):

> Error using
>   matlab.unittest.internal.parameters.validateParametersExistForInputArguments>validateParameters
>   (line 18) Concrete class TFbe does not define a TestParameter property
>   named args for the do_run_time method. Either implement the property
>   or define the class as Abstract.
>
> Error in
>   matlab.unittest.internal.parameters.validateParametersExistForInputArguments
>   (line 5) validateParameters(testClass, 'Test', 'TestParameter');
>
> Error in matlab.unittest.Test.fromTestCase (line 268)
>               validateParametersExistForInputArguments(testClass);
>
> Error in matlab.unittest.internal.RunnableTestContent/run (line 51)
>               suite = Test.fromTestCase(testCase, varargin{:});

---

what changed from version 2016B?

what are TestParameter property named args? ([here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.parameters.testparameter-class.html) thay are described as "Specification of Test Parameter
" - what's that?)

what do i need to change for my test to run in version 2017A-pre-release?

thanks,
Oded

Comment: Since 2017a is a pre-release (and therefore confidential), it may be worth submitting this directly to the Mathworks via their website.

Comment: Have you checked the release notes for this pre-release? That's always the first place one should look for something like this.

Comment: now i bypassed the problem, by changing do_run_time to a non-test method.  this method stores its arguments (args, num_of_iterations) in newly added properties of the class (as hack for passing parameters), and then calls a test method that uses these 2 properties, and does all the testing work.  this does pass the unit test, but I don't want to have such a code in my project.